# Heavy Weights Then Nap?

Tags: weightlifting, strength-training, training

I am on a routine of heavy weights, full body circuit training.  When I am done, I am obviously tired, but sometimes I feel like actually taking a nap.

Are there any ill effects to taking a rest after a heavy weight workout?  ( or any weight training regimine? )

I have always thought you should stay active for a bit after a workout...

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need to stay active?

Comment: Not really, just heard that over the years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make sure to get some food right after training, but a nap after a hard training session sounds good to me. I'd just want to make sure my body has carbohydrate (to replenish intramuscular glycogen stores) and protein (for protein synthesis) and water (to rehydrate) before the nap.

Comment: Though I can't find the article, I do remember reading several years back that Eric Cressey used to tell his athletes to go take a nap after training to help them recover.